# Why line numbers in PhpStorm are different from other text editors?

Tags: command-line, phpstorm, line

Why is number of lines in PhpStorm different from other text editors like notepad or notepad++?

When I see a warning or error from PHP file, the line number of error or warning is exactly the one that exists in the editors like notepad or notepad++, but is different in PhpStorm and is two or three or more lines lower.

**I searched in google and stackoverflow but couldnt find the right answer.**

What is the problem and how can I solve that?

Comment: Please provide screenshots or even better -- small screencast/video that would illustrate the issue. It's not clear at all why you think that the lines are different. You may even be using 2 different files... etc. Without knowing the details I may only say that it's the first time I hear about such issue.

Answer (score 0):

## The problem solved.

The opened PHP file was wrong and was replaced by the original file and I had a mistake.
Thanks